# Link to current post from an array of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Just trying to get my head around the following, probably basic I know. I am looping through an array of records using .each and would like to view the post i click via an ajax request on the same page

```
  <h2>Recent News</h2>
   <ul>
    <% @tynewyddpost.reverse.each do |t| %>
     <li>
       <% single = t.photos.first %>
        <a class="photo" href="#"><%= image_tag(single.avatar.url(:thumbnail_news_images)) %></a>
         <p><%= link_to t.title, tynewyddnews_path(:type => 'tynewyddnews'), :remote => true %></p>
         <p class="date"><%= date_output(t.published_on) %></p>
      </li> 
     <% end %>
    </ul>
```

So when i click the title it will render the same post no matter which record i click.

The partial i render

```
    <div class="post-item">
     <% @tynewyddpost.reverse.each do |t| %>
      <h2><%= t.title %></h2>
       <div id="work-samples"> 
        <% for photo in t.photos %>
         <%= image_tag(photo.avatar.url(:news_images), :class => 'work-sample') %>
        <% end %>
      </div>  
  <p class="post-description"><%= t.comments.html_safe %></p>
   <div class="post-item-panel">
      <ul>
       <li class="date">
        <p><%= date_output(t.published_on) %></p>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
 def tynewyddnews
@title = 'Ty Newydd News'
tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts.reverse
tynewyddpost.pop
@tynewyddpost = tynewyddpost
@tynewyddpostlatest = Post.tynewydd_posts.first
```

end

Scope

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
```

My question is how to get the particular post i have clicked. I cant do

```
<%= @tynewyydpost.title %>
```

As i get undefined method title for array. Bit of theory here i know but how to get an individual record from an array in this instance

Any help appreciated

Comment: Just a simple advice that has nothing to do with your question @Richlewis, use the method `reverse_each` instead of `reverse.each`. There is no reason in reversing the array to iterate over it backwards.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, but i was reversing the array to show my results as i wanted to show the results in reverse order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the id of the post you're clicked on:

```
<p><%= link_to t.title, tynewyddnews_path(:type => 'tynewyddnews', :post_id => t.id), :remote => true %></p>
```

so in your controller you can do

```
@theposticlickedon = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

or

```
@theposticlickedon = Post.tynewydd_posts.find(params[:post_id])
```

However, you also may want to define a different path to show the individual post, instead of the tynewyddnews_path you have in your link.

Comment: thank you, so in my controller @tynewyddpost is rendered like in the question, so is it this instance variable that i change to say your second option? so tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts.reverse becomes tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts.find(params[:id]

Comment: i have used tynewyddnews_path as i would like the post rendered on the same page via ajax, is this not the way to do it?

Comment: I made a correction. I meant find(params[:post_id]). That will still fail when you hit the tynewyddnews page directly (not from the click), which is why you need a different action for your ajax link. Why do you want it to be an ajax call?

Comment: Because the default route of say post/:id is to be viewed by the admin user only so that they can perform CRUD actions.i wanted an area for public viewing of each post.. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Have routes meant to the admin user namespaced under admin. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing. You can have the same routes non-namespaced as public pages. No need to use ajax here, nor recommended

Comment: Ok so this enables the admin to see posts with CRUD options and users to see posts without CRUD options? for clarity would you mind explains how I could achieve by giving the Ajax call a different action, more learning :)

Comment: what I meant is have different routes with limited functionality for public access. For example `resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show]`. Now for admin access `namespace :admin do resources :posts`. Take a look at the link above for info about routes and namespaces

Comment: got this working in the end, still using ajax, took your advice and created separate action to handle it and rather than post_id it was :id => t.id in my link_to.. thanks for your help, it helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in every link ID of this post.

For example:

```
<%= link_to t.title, tynewyddnews_path(:type => 'tynewyddnews'), :post_id=>t.id, :remote => true %>
```

And than specify that in controller action you're calling , by finding this by id

```
@tynewyddnews=Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Than you're partial instance @tynewyddnews will be clicked post